# AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "xmpp"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xmpp, webrtc

I am trying to run gae app without dev_appserver.py, and have following error
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "xmpp"

```
room = webrtc.Room.get_by_key_name(room_key)
```

I found in the  app.yaml inbound_services:
- channel_presence

How to enable channel_presence directly in application.py

Comment: If you aren't using dev_appserver.py, how are you trying to run it?

Comment: I copied google dir from gae sdk into site-packages. I need only channel from gae.

Answer (score 2):

Unless otherwise specified, libraries included with the App Engine SDK are expected only to work within the App Engine environment. You cannot just import the XMPP library included with the App Engine SDK and expect it to work in a non-GAE application.

Comment: It is sad)), can you advise a alternative of gae channel for non-GAE application which is uses Webrtc technology for p2p video. How to connect 2 clients without channel?

Comment: You can look at TyphoonAE (http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/wiki/ChannelAPI), but if you want to use App Engine services, I don't know why you wouldn't use App Engine.

Comment: Legitimate question. The fact that a large part of the application for several months been working on werkzeug, as the server has decided to use gevent, template engine - tenjin, recently decided to add support for webrtc. Therefore, do not want to start all over again, because I just don `t know does the gae gevent and werkzeug and tenjin.